# Table containing multiple equations

Tags: align, tabu, cases

Is there an elegant way to summarize multiple equations from different sources in a table? I need to use this in my thesis; the margins I specified match the geometry of my university's draft.

I've put together the following MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Selection of the fonts
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[libertine,bigdelims,vvarbb,scaled=1.07]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{phv}

%% No overfull hboxes anymore (hopefully)
\usepackage{microtype}

%% to get 1.5 line spacing (actually 1.25)
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

%%% Load math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%% For the tables!
\usepackage{booktabs, tabu}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Table For Stackexchange}

\blindtext[4]

\textbf{How to get rid of the vertical offset between author's name and equation? Any idea how to avoid the \texttt{Overfull hbox}?}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Porosity Correlations from the Literature}
\label{tab:porcorr}
\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{tabu}{X[l] X[l, 6]}
\toprule
\textbf{Reference} & \textbf{Correlation} \\
\midrule
Author a (1985) & 
{\begin{align}
\varepsilon(x) ~&=~ 1 \,-\, 4.5 \left( x \,-\, \frac{7}{9}x^2 \right) (1 \,-\, \varepsilon) \quad \text{for}~ x ~\leq~~0.25 \\
\varepsilon(x) ~&=~ a_1 \exp(-a_2 x) \cos{[a_3 x \,-\, a_4) \pi]}(1 \,-\, \varepsilon) \cdot \varepsilon  ~\text{for}~ x \in (0.25,~8) \\
\text{With:}~ x ~&=~ \frac{R \,-\, r}{d_\mathrm{p}} \nonumber \\
\text{Constants:}~ &a_1 = 0.3463 \quad a_2 = 0.4274 \quad a_3 = 2.4509 \quad a_4 = 2.2011 \nonumber
\end{align}
} \\
Author b (1989) & 
{\begin{align}
\varepsilon(r) ~&=~ \varepsilon \,+\, (1 \,-\, \varepsilon)J_0(a \, r^*) \exp(-b \, r^*) \\
\text{With:} \nonumber \\
a ~&=~ 
\begin{cases}
8.243 \,-\, \frac{12.98}{D/d_\mathrm{p} \,-\, 3.156} & \text{for}~ 2.61 \leq D/d_\mathrm{p} \leq 13 \\
7.383 \,-\, \frac{2.932}{D/d_\mathrm{p} \,-\, 9.864} & \text{for}~ D/d_\mathrm{p} > 13
\end{cases}
\nonumber \\
b ~&=~ 0.304 \,-\, \frac{0.724}{D/d_\mathrm{p}}, \quad r^* ~=~ \frac{r}{d_\mathrm{p}}, \quad \varepsilon ~=~ 0.379 \,+\, \frac{0.078}{D/d_\mathrm{p} \,-\, 1.80} \nonumber
\end{align}
} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Table containing multiple equations and their source]

The two main issues are:

1. There's a notable vertical spacing between the author's names and the equations. How to get them to the same height?
2. There's an overfull hbox on line 56, which is especially ugly since not only the text but also the top-, mid- and bottomrule of the tabu reach into the margin. (Compare the position of "will" beneath the table with the bottomline.) How to avoid this? I know I can insert a manual linebreak, but isn't there a better way?

Since this is my first post on TeX.SX, please feel free to improve it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: not directly relevant to the question, but (1) `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, and (2) `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`.  therefore, it's not necessary to load either `amsmath` or `amsfonts` explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> There's a notable vertical spacing between the author's names and the equations. How to get them to the same height?

Instead of using an `align` environment, you could use an `aligned` environment together with the positioning specifier `[t]`.

I would also recommend that you

- omit all `\,` and `~` directives, which currently serve to override TeX's own spacing rules (but you don't do it in an entirely consistent way)
- get rid of the curly braces around `\cos[a_3 x - a_4) \pi]`
- use a `dcases` environment instead of a `cases` environment.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Selection of the fonts
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[libertine,bigdelims,vvarbb,scaled=1.07]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{phv}

%% No overfull hboxes anymore (hopefully)
\usepackage{microtype}

%% to get 1.5 line spacing (actually 1.25)
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

%%% Load math packages
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{units}

%% For the tables!
\usepackage{booktabs, tabu}
%\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Jzero}{\mathit{J_0}}

\begin{document}

%\chapter{Table For Stackexchange}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
%\blindtext[4]

%\textbf{How to get rid of the vertical offset between author's name and equation? Any idea how to avoid the \texttt{Overfull hbox}?}

\begin{table}[h]
%\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
%\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
%\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
\caption{Porosity Correlations from the Literature}
\label{tab:porcorr}
\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{tabu}{@{} X[l] X[l, 6] @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Reference} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Correlation}} \\
\midrule
Author a (1985) 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\varepsilon(x) = 
\begin{dcases}
1 - 4.5 \left( x - \tfrac{7}{9}x^2 \right) (1 - \varepsilon) 
    & \text{for $x \leq0.25$} \\
a_1 \exp(-a_2 x) \cos[a_3 x - a_4) \pi](1 - \varepsilon) \varepsilon  
    & \text{for $x \in (0.25,8)$} \end{dcases}\\[1ex]
&\text{With: $x = (R - r)/d_\mathrm{p}$}  \\
&\text{Constants:  $a_1 = 0.3463$, $a_2 = 0.4274$, $a_3 = 2.4509$, $a_4 = 2.2011$}
\end{aligned}$ \\[2ex]
Author b (1989) 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]
\varepsilon(r) &= \varepsilon + (1 - \varepsilon) \Jzero(a  r^*) \exp(-b  r^*) \\[1.5ex]
\text{With:}\\
a &=
\begin{dcases}
8.243 - \frac{12.98}{D/d_\mathrm{p} - 3.156} & \text{for $2.61 \leq D/d_\mathrm{p} \leq 13$} \\[1ex]
7.383 - \frac{2.932}{D/d_\mathrm{p} - 9.864} & \text{for $D/d_\mathrm{p} > 13$}
\end{dcases}
 \\[1ex]
b &= 0.304 - \frac{0.724}{D/d_\mathrm{p}}, \quad r^* = \frac{r}{d_\mathrm{p}}, \quad \varepsilon = 0.379 + \frac{0.078}{D/d_\mathrm{p} - 1.80} 
\end{aligned}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

%\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum** to address the OP's follow-up comment: To combine the simplicity of the `aligned` environment that's used in the example above with the ability to assign equation numbers to the main equations (and to create cross-references), you may wish to provide an extra column (or type `r) in the`tabu` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Selection of the fonts
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[libertine,bigdelims,vvarbb,scaled=1.07]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{phv}

%% No overfull hboxes anymore (hopefully)
\usepackage{microtype}

%% to get 1.5 line spacing (actually 1.25)
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

%%% Load math packages
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{units}

%% For the tables!
\usepackage{booktabs, tabu}
%\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Jzero}{\mathit{J_0}}

\begin{document}

%\chapter{Table For Stackexchange}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
%\blindtext[4]

%\textbf{How to get rid of the vertical offset between author's name and equation? Any idea how to avoid the \texttt{Overfull hbox}?}

\begin{table}[h]
%\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
%\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
%\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
\caption{Porosity Correlations from the Literature}
\label{tab:porcorr}
\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{tabu}{@{} X[l] X[l, 6] r @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Reference} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Correlation}} \\
\midrule
Author a (1985)
& $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\varepsilon(x) =
\begin{dcases}
1 - 4.5 \left( x - \tfrac{7}{9}x^2 \right) (1 - \varepsilon)
    & \text{for $x \leq0.25$} \\
a_1 \exp(-a_2 x) \cos[a_3 x - a_4) \pi](1 - \varepsilon) \varepsilon
    & \text{for $x \in (0.25,8)$} \end{dcases} \\[1ex]
&\text{With: $x = (R - r)/d_\mathrm{p}$}  \\
&\text{Constants:  $a_1 = 0.3463$, $a_2 = 0.4274$, $a_3 = 2.4509$, $a_4 = 2.2011$}
\end{aligned}$ &
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:author_a}(\theequation)\\[2ex]
Author b (1989)
& $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\varepsilon(r) = \varepsilon + (1 - \varepsilon) \Jzero(a  r^*) \exp(-b  r^*) \\[1.5ex]
&\text{With:}\\
&a =
\begin{dcases}
8.243 - \frac{12.98}{D/d_\mathrm{p} - 3.156} & \text{for $2.61 \leq D/d_\mathrm{p} \leq 13$} \\[1ex]
7.383 - \frac{2.932}{D/d_\mathrm{p} - 9.864} & \text{for $D/d_\mathrm{p} > 13$}
\end{dcases}
 \\[1ex]
&b = 0.304 - \frac{0.724}{D/d_\mathrm{p}}\,, \quad 
 r^* = \frac{r}{d_\mathrm{p}}\,, \quad 
 \varepsilon = 0.379 + \frac{0.078}{D/d_\mathrm{p} - 1.80}
\end{aligned}$ & 
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:author_b}(\theequation)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

Here are cross-references to equations \eqref{eq:author_a} and \eqref{eq:author_b}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've combined both answers in my document now. The issue with your solution @Mico is that equations are not numbered. However, I'm referencing them later in the text, so the numbers are necessary. Any solution for that in combination with the {aligned} environment?

Comment: @Emanuele - I've posted a follow-up to my answer in which I show how to combine the simplicity of the `aligned` environment with the ability to generate equation numbers (and create cross-references to the equations).

Answer (score 1):

I made two small edits
* Put negative vertical space to align the math and authors.  Unfortunately, this needs to be manually tuned.  (probably is a more elegant way)
* I adjusted the column proportions (ck the tabu manual page 10, http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabu/tabu.pdf ) to eliminate most of the Overfull \hbox.  However, I suspect to eliminate it you will have to rewrite the offending equation to use less horizontal space.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Selection of the fonts
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[libertine,bigdelims,vvarbb,scaled=1.07]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{phv}

%% No overfull hboxes anymore (hopefully)
\usepackage{microtype}

%% to get 1.5 line spacing (actually 1.25)
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

%%% Load math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{units}

%% For the tables!
\usepackage{booktabs, tabu}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Table For Stackexchange}

\blindtext[4]

\textbf{How to get rid of the vertical offset between author's name and equation? Any idea how to avoid the \texttt{Overfull hbox}?}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Porosity Correlations from the Literature}
\label{tab:porcorr}
\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{tabu}{X X[1, 7.5]}
\toprule
\textbf{Reference} & \textbf{Correlation} \\
\midrule
Author a (1985)& 
\vspace{-2.1em}{\begin{align}
\varepsilon(x) ~&=~ 1 \,-\, 4.5 \left( x \,-\, \frac{7}{9}x^2 \right) (1 \,-\, \varepsilon) \quad \text{for}~ x ~\leq~~0.25 \\
\varepsilon(x) ~&=~ a_1 \exp(-a_2 x) \cos{[a_3 x \,-\, a_4) \pi]}(1 \,-\, \varepsilon) \cdot \varepsilon  ~\text{for}~ x \in (0.25,~8) \\
\text{With:}~ x ~&=~ \frac{R \,-\, r}{d_\mathrm{p}} \nonumber \\
\text{Constants:}~ &a_1 = 0.3463 \quad a_2 = 0.4274 \quad a_3 = 2.4509 \quad a_4 = 2.2011 \nonumber
\end{align}
}\\
Author b (1989) & 
\vspace{-2.1em}{\begin{align}
\varepsilon(r) ~&=~ \varepsilon \,+\, (1 \,-\, \varepsilon)J_0(a \, r^*) \exp(-b \, r^*) \\
\text{With:} \nonumber \\
a ~&=~ 
\begin{cases}
8.243 \,-\, \frac{12.98}{D/d_\mathrm{p} \,-\, 3.156} & \text{for}~ 2.61 \leq D/d_\mathrm{p} \leq 13 \\
7.383 \,-\, \frac{2.932}{D/d_\mathrm{p} \,-\, 9.864} & \text{for}~ D/d_\mathrm{p} > 13
\end{cases}
\nonumber \\
b ~&=~ 0.304 \,-\, \frac{0.724}{D/d_\mathrm{p}}, \quad r^* ~=~ \frac{r}{d_\mathrm{p}}, \quad \varepsilon ~=~ 0.379 \,+\, \frac{0.078}{D/d_\mathrm{p} \,-\, 1.80} \nonumber
\end{align}
} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

And here is just the table:
[image]